# How to use a NLopt solver together with MathProgBase?

Tags: julia, nlopt

I would like to use the `MathProgBase` interface to formulate an optimization problem.  Furthermore, I would like to use an open-source solver, such as `NLopt` (or any other).

The doc at https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl#using-with-mathprogbase mentions that `NLopt` can be called via `MathProgBase`.  Unfortunately, I can not find a fool-proof example.  On the other hand, `MathProgBase` does not mention `NLopt`.  So let's try it.  Here is the code:

```
using NLopt, MathProgBase
quadprog([0., 0., 0.],[2. 1. 0.; 1. 2. 1.; 0. 1. 2.],[1. 2. 3.; 1. 1. 0.],'>',[4., 1.],-Inf,Inf,NLoptSolver(algorithm=:NLOPT_AUGLAG))
```

I get the following error message:

```
`loadproblem!` has no method matching loadproblem!(::NLoptMathProgModel, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Symbol)
while loading In[1], in expression starting on line 2

 in quadprog at /Users/harmeling/.julia/v0.3/MathProgBase/src/HighLevelInterface/quadprog.jl:46
```

What's wrong?  I am also fine with any other open source solver.  Important for me is to use `MathProgBase` calling convention like `quadprog`.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The NLopt documentation now has such an example of using JuMP via the `MathProgBase` interface https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl#tutorial

Answer (score 0):

NLopt includes a collection of algorithms for solving general nonlinear optimization problems. Currently, only the nonlinear, [derivative-based interface](http://mathprogbasejl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nlp.html) is implemented. So if you want to solve a quadratic problem, you'll have to go through this more general interface. It's certainly possible for this to be done automatically, but it hasn't been implemented yet.

For `quadprog`, Ipopt would be a much more powerful solver than NLopt. Ipopt currently supports the linear interface and the nonlinear interface, but not yet the quadratic interface. I intend to implement this soon.

Comment: Actually, meanwhile I did implement the quadprog interface for Ipopt.  You can download it at github.com/harmeling/Quadprog.jl Right now I put it there with a pull request for METADATA.  However, feel free to include it at the right location to provide the interface for Ipopt.  I am assuming you will know where to put it.